# Angular e2e protractor browser.wait doesnt work

Tags: angular, protractor

I have a problem with a browser.wait function in my project:

```
 it("should display plan description", async () => {        
    //changing description in LIC
    await app.navigateTo(LIC_PLANS_URL);
    browser.sleep(2000);
    dashboard.filtrByTitle = PLAN_TITLE;
    browser.sleep(2000);
    await dashboard.plansEdit.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    dashboard.description = PLAN_TEST;
    browser.sleep(2000);
    await dashboard.savePlan.click();
    
    //checking that the plan description has changed in ACC
    app.navigateTo(ACC_DASHBOARD);
    browser.sleep(4000);
    expect(dashboard.planDescription.getText()).toContain("automation_test");
```

Can i do something with this browser.sleep functions? I thing that this is not a proper way to make test but without this it makes timeout errors.

I was trying to solve this with:

```
var EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dashboard.plansEdit),5000);
```

But it doesnt help at all, im using protractor 7.0.0.
Anyone know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct when saying that `browser.sleep()` is not a good practice and should be replaced with explicit waits.

In the particular case of `visibilityOf()`, Protractor assumes the element is already present and tries to locate it right away, if it's not present, thus not visible, it'll throw an exception. But you could use the `presenceOf()` method which waits for the element to be present in the html DOM for any given amount of time that you specify (default is 5000ms).

You could make a function that waits for the presence of an element then for its visibility/clickability:

```js
const EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;

const waitForEl = async (ele) = {
    await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(ele), 5000);
    return await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele), 5000);
};

// call it:

await waitForEl(dashboard.plansEdit);
```